# How to pass a logged in user's id/name to the db in a hidden field?

Tags: mysql, user-input

I need help. I am pretty new to forms and mysql.
I have a user form with 2 fields that gets sent to db on submit. I need the db to also be popluated with the submitting user's ID or username. Is this best accomplished with a hidden input field?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: session variables would be better. You also probably don't need to submit the username. That should just be stored in your users table and you can look it up there using the user ID instead of having it stored in several places. Saves you some space.

Answer (score 1):

The hidden field will work, but is risky. Someone can edit the html on their machine and submit the form with someone elses id; effectively hacking the system.

The common approach is to store the user's id in Session when the user logs in. If there is a user id then there must be some code for username password verification. Find that code. There, if password matches, store the user id in Session. How you do that - google it.

Now that you have the user id in session, while inserting data, use the input fields from the form and user id from the session.

Comment: ok. so i have the name of the user added to the session but it doesnt make it to the db. The other values do, but not $value3                   Here is code:                                                                                            $value = $_POST['quantity'];
$value2 = $_POST['color'];
$value3 = $_SESSION['name_of_user'] = $row['name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO record (

     quantity,
     color,                                                                                                                 ) 
VALUES (
    '$value',
    '$value2')";

Comment: previous code has been corrected. "name" has been added to the INSERT and $value3 into the VALUES and it still isnt making it to the db. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can take input type hidden element in the form and when you are going to submit the form you can get that values as same as you get not text values, then insert values to database, i hope you know about insert query in mysql.
thank you